# How to save data into database with threads in python

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Hello everyone i'm new to threading so I don't have a lott of experience in it. I have looked online on how to thread but I couldn't find one. This is how my code looks like and the commented out code's are what I have tried to make it work but it didn't work. what our code does it fetches the data from a json file that we have in our folder and it puts every data that's in the file into a variable. that variable is then put into `EventModel.insert_data()` So we can do a insert function into the database

```
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from api.data.data_endpoint_fetcher import DataEndpointFetcher
from api.models.event import EventModel


class DBAddEvents:
    @classmethod
    def add_all_events(cls):
        start = timer()
        combined_events = DataEndpointFetcher.combine_matching_events()
        for event in combined_events['events']:
            try:
                road_name = event['lanelocation']['road']

                avg_speed = event["avgspeed"].get("kmph")

                flow_count = event["flow"].get("count")

                ts_event = event['ts_event']
                uuid = event['measuring_point_id'].get("uuid")

            except:
                continue

            EventModel.insert_data(road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid)
        end = timer()
        print(end - start)
DBAddEvents.add_all_events()
```

I have tried the couple things to get it to work:

```
# first attempt at trying to get the code to work
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = Thread(target=DBAddEvents.add_all_events)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
    print('done')

# second attempt at trying to get the code to work
for i in range(10):
     Thread(target=DBAddEvents.add_all_events).start()
     sleep(1)

# and this was my last attempt to get the code to work
 thread1 = Thread(target=DBAddEvents.add_all_events)
 thread2 = Thread(target=DBAddEvents.add_all_events)

 thread1.start()
 thread2.start()

 print('Waiting for the thread...')

 thread1.join()
 thread2.join()
```

if you need more information about something let me know and i'll try to answer as soon as possible

Comment: saving data into a database has nothing to do with pthreads, please focus your question on something more specific

Comment: @ichramm true, i wanna ptrhreads the reading the data from json and putting the data in the variables and with that saving data into database will come

Comment: have you made any of those parts work on their own before?

Comment: @ichramm No I haven't tried that, I started on implementing it in this def

Comment: elaborate on what exactly is not working. it seems like you catch exception and just ignore them, print them and post the result so we would know how to help. also this is a GREAT guide for python threading https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/#starting-a-thread